# Webform node titles - 6x

Tags: nodes, webforms

I have a custom content type that has a webform. One of the components is the node title.
Is there a way to use a token to pull the node title instead of typing it?
I've tried setting %title as default but that simply spits back the token at me as text "%title".
Please advice.

Comment: I don't what you are trying to do.  Are you trying automate the title of the node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last I checked, Webform didn't pick up a title token.

But it is possible to send the page's url in an email by using the %server[key] token.

For example, in the Webform tab > e-Mails subtab > E-mail template, include:

```
http://yourdomain.com%server[REQUEST_URI]
```

See [this page](http://drupal.org/node/296453#webform-url-default) for more info.

EDIT: [This](http://drupal.org/node/873354#comment-3460248) comment may have a full solution